# How can I train my internal hip rotators?

Tags: strength-training, hip

I think it may be useful to train my internal hip rotators.
"If you squat or deadlift and push your knees out, you’re strengthening the external rotators and without also strengthening the internal rotators, your hip joint will get out of balance, resulting in dysfunctional movement patterns, mobility restrictions and eventually, pain and injuries."(1)

I found an interesting [exercise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygFfx9WbH9w) (jump to 2.12) that I think may do the trick.
I need help in understanding if this will both train external and internal rotation?
Here is my anatomical analysis of a right side kettlebell "swing" with respect to hip rotators:
(I think this is biomechanically similar to a right punch so I will refer to the "swing" as a "punch".)

My right leg loads up the "punch" by pulling itself into internal rotation.
As I deliver the "punch" much of the force comes from my right leg going from internal to external rotation.
I would therefore think that this punch like movement trains both external and internal rotations of the hips?

Is there other (loaded) exercises that trains internal hip rotation you can recommend?
I would think a cable machine could be used for this.
I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhXxfGMggB8). Does this train internal or external rotation or both?

(1) [Hip Control](https://www.precisionmovement.coach/hip-control/?utm_medium=Button&utm_source=Blog&utm_campaign=Precision%20Movement%20Store&utm_content=hc%20%7C%20v1)

Answer (score 1):

Good that you found precision movement. If you go deeper in their content you will find plenty of exercises for internal hip rotation strength. For starter you can get down in the 90/90 position and press your inner thigh against the ground. Then you can rise up from that position by activating your adductor that is against the ground.

Here is another video to get familiar with the concept.
https://youtu.be/qw7PosB84vQ

Comment: Thank you for your help! I just tested this exercise and found it very hard to do, so I will definitely be doing this for some weeks. 
This exercise is by itself an isolation exercise and also feels like a not very natural movement. These sorts of exercises are not my favourites.
Ideally I would like to hear something like: "do loaded carries every other day for a month and this will fix your problems".
However I understand that sitting at a desk for 8 hours for x years is not very natural either and it may require "unnatural" and complex solutions to get better, especially to start with.

Comment: I agree with your opinion on how fun it is to do these types of exercises. But after 15 years of seeing different specialists in order to be able to keep playing soccer ( now 57 years old) I found that these exercises, when done in a relaxed and consistent manner, really start helping. After two months i start to learn which exercises give the most bang for the buck and can focus on these and add a few tweaks of my own ....